# why isn't the debugger aware of methods on my Core Data generated managed object classes? (code attached)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, core-data

why isn't the debugger aware of methods on my Core Data generated managed object classes? (code attached) So:

- I have an XCode generated managed Core Data object class called WEView
- I notice the debugger don't seem to be aware of it's methods?
- See below in the console output.  The initial "po self.weView" seems to work, but then when referring any of the objects instance variables doesn't?

Console Output

```
(gdb) po self.weView
<WEView: 0x4f6a3f0> (entity: WEView; id: 0x4f68710 <x-coredata://CB3E1660-4BA8-4700-ADDB-A32CD44D56B6/WEView/p3> ; data: {
    title = "Weekend Items";
    weEndDayTime = "(...not nil..)";
    weStartDayTime = "(...not nil..)";
})
(gdb) po self.weView.title
There is no member named title.
(gdb) po [self.weView title]
Target does not respond to this message selector.
(gdb)
```

header - produced by Xcode

```
@interface WEView : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id weStartDayTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id weEndDayTime;

@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats because there really is no ivar named title and also no getter or setter pair. Thats also why you use `@dynamic` and not `@synthesize`. When you access eg. title, this will be something like this in reality:

```
[myObject valueForKey:@"title"];
```

Likewise, setting the title is something like this:

```
[myObject setValue:foo forKey:@"title"];
```

So basically is a NSManagedObject just a wrapper around a database fetch or a access from the cache, but you will never access some real ivars of the object (you can try the runtime functions to determine the ivars of an NSManagedObject subclass).

If you still want to use the `[self.view title]`, you need to overwrite it. Here is an example:

```
- (NSString *)title
{
   NSString *value;
   [self willAccessValueForKey:@"title"];
   value = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"title"];
   [self didAccessValueForKey:@"title"];

   return value;
}
```

Of course thats not a atomic getter and its slower than the normal way, but hey, it works.

Comment: oh - ok - any recommendations re debugging - do most people just leave things as they are and understand the situation, or is there some tweaks perhaps that are possible to assist in debugging?  I'm guessing the former but I thought I would ask...oh and I did read someone recommend "mogenerator" over XCode's code generator but I'm guessing it would produce the same sort of code perhaps?

Comment: He already gave you the string for debugging - simply say "po [myObject valueForKey:@"title"]" or in your exact case "po [self.weView valueForKey:@"title"]"

Comment: yep understood that - was asking about tweaks in the class so that one could use "po self.weView.title"

Comment: @Greg: You can "overwrite" the accessor/setter to set the value/read it. I've updated the answer with an example.